# How to get and separate 2 php vars with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a receiver:

```
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
```

And this is how I am sending the vars:

```
      echo json_encode($cat_name);
      echo json_encode($cat_id);
```

console gives:

```
"milano"205
```

I'd need those two vars to be separated in order to use them in different context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making it an actual object:

```
echo json_encode(array('cat_name' => $cat_name, 'cat_id' => $cat_id));
```

Comment: that's nice, but I tried then           `console.log(data[0]);
          console.log(data[1]);` and i couldn't access those objects

Comment: you need to set the ajax type to json or use parse json function

Comment: Do you mean dataType: "json", ?

Comment: yeah, then you'll just use `console.log(data.cat_name);console.log(data.cat_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a JSON array as a response and parse it in the Javascript end or accept it as JSON.

PHP

```
echo json_encode(['cat_name' => $cat_name, 'cat_id' => $cat_id]);
```

Javascript

```
dataType: "json", //ajax call option
....
vad d = JSON.parse(data) //or this
```

Then you can call `d.cat_name` and `d.cat_id`